# Redux Saga not triggering API call when action is dispatched

Tags: redux, generator, redux-saga

I've used redux saga before but i'm still fairly new to it. Anyways, I seem to be running into a problem in the code below.

At the top, you will see the action creator I am using to fire off this AJAX request. **Redux is properly dispatching this action and is logging the `LOAD_USER_REQUEST` type in my console** however the function chain stops there. In the code below, you will see that `LOAD_USER_REQUEST` should call the `loadUserDetails` generator which should then call the `userLogin` with the payload received in my action creator.

Let me know if I can supply any additional info that may help. Thanks in advance :)

```js
// Action Creator for LOAD_USER_REQUEST.
export const getExistingUser = ({email = 'tt@gmail.com', password = '12345'} = {}) => ({
type: LOAD_USER_REQUEST,
payload: {email, password}
})

// API call being used in loadUserDetails Saga
export const userLogin = ({email = 'tt@gmail.com', password = '12345'} = {}) => {
  return axios.post(`${API}auth/login`, {
    email, 
    password
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.token);
    let user = res.data.user;
    console.log(user);
    return user;
    })
  .catch(err => new Error('userLogin err', err));
}


// Sagas
// loadUserDetails Saga - Should call fn above userLogin with payload from action creator
function* loadUserDetails(payload) {
    const user = yield call(userLogin(payload));
    yield put({type: LOAD_USER_SUCCESS, user}); // Yields effect to the reducer specifying the action type and user details
}
export function* watchRequest() {
  yield* takeLatest(LOAD_USER_REQUEST, loadUserDetails);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At first, does your entry point to saga configured well? You should add saga-middleware in store creation, and don't forget to invoke saga process manager by `runSaga` method.

At second, why you re-delegate generator instance to up-level? Maybe it's meant to `yield takeLatest(LOAD_USER_REQUEST, loadUserDetails);` without `yield*` operator? Is has quite different semantics.

At third, by API reference, `call` effect takes function or generator reference, but you provide promise object. Maybe it's meant `const user = yield call(() => userLogin(payload));` or `const user = yield call(userLogin, payload);`?